# Disjoint unions and closed subsets.

Tags: general-topology

Problem: Let $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ be a collection of topological spaces.
And $X=\coprod_{i\in I} X_i$ be equipped with the disjoint union topology.

F $\subseteq$ $X$ is closed $\iff$ the intersection of $F$ with each $X_i$ is closed.

I know that..

If F is closed in X then $F^c$ is open in $X$. Hence $F^c \cap X_i^*$ is open in $X_i^*$ for each i $\iff $ for each i, $X_i^* \backslash F$ is open in $X_i^*$ 
I'm not sure what else to do, may I have hints?

Comment: Let's do each direction separately. First $\Leftarrow$. If $F\cap X_i$ is closed in $X_i$, then $X_i\setminus F$ is open in $X_i$. But, $F = \left(\bigsqcup_{i\in I}X_i\setminus F\right)^c$, so $F$ is closed in $X$.

Comment: Next, let's tackle $\Rightarrow$. If $F\subseteq X$ is closed, then $G=X\setminus F$ is open. By the definition of the topology, $G\cap X_i$ is open for each $i$. But, $F\cap X_i=X_i\setminus G$, and $X_i\setminus G$ is the relative complement of $G\cap X_i$ in $X_i$. So, $F\cap X_i$ is closed, and we are done.

Comment: @Don Thousand $X_i\neq X_i^*$ further, Im not trying to show that the intersection is closed in $X_i$

Comment: The topological sum,  a topology on the set $\cup_{i\in I}(X_i\times \{i\}), $ not on the set  $\prod_{i\in I}X_i.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet The OP wrote $\coprod_{i\in I} X_i$

Comment: @PaulFrost . I had not seen that symbol before and mis-took it for $\prod.$